# Slight tweaking of grammar required in the prompt shown when adding another answer to a question where one already has multiple answers

Tags: feature-request, bug, popups, plurals

When adding an answer to a question, which a user has already answered, the user is prompted:

> Are you sure you want to add another answer?
> You could use the edit link to refine and improve your existing answer, instead.

In this message, it is assumed that the user has **only one *existing answer***.

However, if the user has already answered that question twice or more before, the grammar in the prompt is wrong and would do better with the word "**answers**".

> Are you sure you want to add another answer?
> You could use the edit link to refine and improve your existing **answers**, instead.

Also, since each answer would have a separate *edit link* (not ***the* edit link**), that part may be removed from the prompt shown when answering the same question for third or more time, making the prompt:

> Are you sure you want to add another answer?
> You could refine and improve your existing answers, instead.